# How to take a SUM of COUNTIFs across many sheets using a loop to supply sheet names from a list

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to create a data table for a user who has multiple columns with varying lists of names. They have created a new sheet for each date needed. They now want one sheet that will show the total number of times a name has appeared in each column.

I brute forced a solution that used Sum(List of COUNTIFs the name appeared in a column for that date/sheet), but this of course isnt feasible to continue

I was wondering if there is a way, probably in VBA, to make a loop to automate this by drawing from a list of sheet names that have been entered already. If I can automatically populate the cells next to the first name on the list, I can easily fill the rest of the table

If you have a better idea of how to implement this, or need more info, please let me know

-No name will appear more than once in a range
-there are 9 ranges per sheet to check
-there will be a total of 180 sheets to count, but not all are created

```
=SUM(COUNTIF('8-5-19'!$A$2:$A$11,$A3),COUNTIF('8-6-19'!$A$2:$A$11,$A3),COUNTIF....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub SumAll()

For Each cell In Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:A10")
    N = 0
    If cell.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "Data" Then
            For Each rngCheck In sht.Range("A2:A10")
                If cell.Value = rngCheck.Value Then
                    N = N + 1
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = N
Next

End Sub
```

[image]